# Можно ли использовать видеокарту для вычислений?

Tags: python, производительность, видеокарта

Можно ли использовать видеокарту вместо процессора для вычислений в python? Если да, то как?

Comment: Ищите NUMBA - https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python

Comment: или OpenCV или OpenGL или любой иной фреймворк для доступа к видеокарте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как поддержки CUDA у python нет, но есть обертка PyCUDA, если у Вас видеокарта от NVidia: https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/, либо NUMBA, как написали выше.
Вот статтья на сравнение этих двух: https://habr.com/ru/post/317328/
И пособие в котором описано больше по GPU+Python: https://cmp.phys.msu.ru/sites/default/files/GPUPython.pdf